# What is the technical name for the [cable] in a laptop that connects to the [LCD]

Tags: laptop, hdmi, dvi, lcd

I wanted to google it and learn about the connector; with the ultimate goal of learning how to turn it into a DVI, VGA or HDMI 
(To turn a naked laptop LCD into an ad hoc monitor)

But when I started, I realized I didnt even know what I was googling.

Comment: Maybe interface or interconnect?

Comment: I think it's informally called an LVDS cable or LVDS ribbon cable, even though LVDS is the protocol and not the cable or connector, technically.

Comment: LVDS if its an older monitor. eDP if its a newer one (Apparently the current ipad retinas use them). There's fairly inexpensive kits with the cables, driver boards (you need one) and everything else on ebay, and howtos floating online for the former. eDP primarily needs a breakout board.

Comment: Eh, apparently the standard is called FPD-Link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FPD-Link

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Thanks much, That is extremely useful. Even the ipad bit, Ive actually repaired a lot of ipads and a bunch of tablets, but the names of... well really anything, never occured to me to memorize. && The "kits" I have seen, "LCD Inverters", which ya, theyre cheap, but this is all for the sake of science - and im tinkering with an AIO TouchScreen PC (Dell Inspiron One 2305) Which would be nice to have a KVM switch to my Workstation. Thanks again.

Comment: @ultrasawblade LVDS you say, Brilliant! As ive fixed many laptops, I know the cables are proprietary and vary, but I assumed they had to be sharing some kind of protocol between them as an ISArchitechture. But im one of those terminology handicapped people. Whats in a name? Dunno... forgot it anyways. Thanks again.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek And the winning point to you! Did some reading just now - So [FPD-Link] uses [LVDS] which is a means of sending digital signals through cables with low voltages. Thanks twice. Please post these two in one answer

Comment: Also, this is a dupe. I've posted a fairly complete answer to the original, least to the full extent of what I know aboyt these things.

Comment: @journeymanGeek - Am i reading this right: The LVDS-FDP cable is a scattered* then recombined RGB signal?

Comment: LCD inverters are the bits that power the oldschool cold cathode backlights. *Not* the driver boards. And I have no idea about the electronic signal bits. Its beyond my ken. ;p

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - ahh, i see.
So, Looks here that the whole function is...
1 - a Source RGB analog style signal along with a clock sync signal is
2 - Scattered with time division into different wires
To lower the voltage and its resulting EM interference 
3 - Which is then recombined at the other end into an RGB signal  4 - Which is then translated by the LCD control board, which is responsible for directly controlling the LCD display.

And the inverter is what powers the CC light behind it.
/Snaps , I now know what i need to know. Thankyou so much